# Will my Lenovo One Key Recovery work if I install Ubuntu on my Ideapad U410?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, lenovo-laptop

I own a Lenovo Ideapad U410. Being a game developer the first thing that I wanted to do is install Ubuntu. But I don't want to lose the Windows 7 that ships with the laptop.

So, I wanted to know if the Lenovo One Key Recovery mechanism is capable of restoring the Windows 7, from the hidden recovery partition, after I install Ubunutu and enable Grub boot loader?

Note: I am already aware that an alternative would be to create Factory Restore disks, to restore when necessary. But I cannot immediately do it unless I buy an External DVD Burner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't touch delete the recovery partition while installing Ubuntu (e.g. selecting "Replace Windows with Ubuntu"), it should be usable from the Recovery Key.

Why don't you try dual booting though? I assume you already have Windows installed?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, as long as that partition is left in place, the system can be recovered.  I have an ideapad s205.  When I first was trying to get linux to work, I had quite a time getting grub to work (Never did get it working with grub2) so I could have a dual boot system (mostly for those few times I absolutely need a windows system).  At least two or three times I made the system unbootable.  When I hit the recovery button it repartitioned the hard drive and restored the disk to the state it came from the factory.